# deploying django to heroku

Tags: python, django, deployment, heroku

Hi Folks so I followed the guid to deploying django on heroku here

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

but my server keeps crashing on heroku with this error any thoughts or direction is greatly appreciated.

```
2013-02-12T19:27:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2013-02-12T19:27:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2013-02-12T19:27:40+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/eduudle/settings.py", line 15, in   <module>
2013-02-12T19:27:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     DATABASES = { 'default': {dj_database_url.config()}}
2013-02-12T19:27:40+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
2013-02-12T19:27:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-12T19:27:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the issue the document is dated so following what it has wont work based on this

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/45

What I had originally would have worked but i added too many curly brackets

So instead of

```
 DATABASES = { 'default': {dj_database_url.config()}}
```

use

```
 DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config()}
```

Answer (score 2):

the  [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings) suggest format for databases should be

`DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()`

not

`DATABASES['default'] =  {dj_database_url.config()}`

Comment: thanks that still wouldn't have worked but it put me on the right track :)